# Using filter opacity as a fallback for rgba?

Tags: html, css, transparency

I want to use RGBA so that I can have text in an opaque div container without making said text transparent. I have the following right now:

```
      .container {
         background-color: #5e82a4;
         opacity: 0.9;
         -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
          filter: alpha(opacity=90);
      }
```

The downside to this method is the text becomes transparent inside the div element What I would rather do is:

```
     .container {
         background-color: rgba(94,130,164,0.9);
      }
```

The only catch here is RGBA is unsupported by IE8 and below. Is there a way to use RGBA first, but if the browser is IE8 or lower (not compatible), use the first method?

Comment: You could use conditional comments [Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to include another stylesheet or class for older browsers .

Comment: Also does not apply to transparency but using [Pie](http://css3pie.com/) can help with things like rounded corners and gradients for older IE versions.

Comment: I updated my original answer with another resource that may be of some use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to achieve transparent backgrounds with older versions of IE is by using a 2x2 transparent PNG as the background image.

You can also use conditional comments in your HTML:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    ...
<![endif]-->
```

Lastly (and I personally don't recommend this), you can use CSS hacks: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/

UPDATE: I also found [this](http://hammerspace.co.uk/2011/10/cross-browser-alpha-transparent-background-css) resource which talks a lot about the same issue.

Comment: @jessikwa No problem! If you are satisfied with the answer, don't forget to mark it as correct. :)